# Adding more nodes to the center of "star" layout - igraph

Tags: r, visualization, igraph

I would like to create a net-graph, that will have 2 nodes in the middle and the rest of the nodes surround them. The edges go from nodes "A" and "B" to the rest of nodes but they are not connected with each other.

I found that layout "star" from `igraph` package will suit me probably the most.
It is theoretically possible to add more nodes in the center of "star" [(manual page)](https://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_as_star.html) but it does not work for me, as regardless specifying two nodes in `center` parameter there is still only one.

```
#data
set.seed(1)
name <- LETTERS

a <- data.frame(from = "A", to = name)
b <- data.frame(from = "B", to = name)

sample <- rbind(a,b)
sample <- sample[-c(1,2,27,28), ] #please note removed edges between A-A, A-B, B-B, and B-A

#plot
g <- graph_from_data_frame(sample)
plot(g, layout = layout_as_star(g, center = V(g)[c("A", "B")]) )
```

[image]

Comment: After all, I found a similar problem and its solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868214/how-to-create-a-polar-network-graph-multiple-rings-in-igraph-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that `layout_as_star` allows multiple centers. 
The `center` argument on the help page that you refer to only 
allows you to specify which one node is the center, not multiple 
centers.  So to get what you want,  you need to do more of the 
layout yourself. Here is one way to get a graph in the form that 
you wanted. I use `layout_as_star` to lay out all of the nodes 
except for one of the centers. But we do not want both "centers"
at the exact center of the circle or they would overlap. So I move
the center and make a spot for the second "center".

```
library(igraph)

s1 = make_star(25, mode="out")
V(s1)$name = LETTERS[-2]

s2 = make_star(25, mode="out")
V(s2)$name = LETTERS[-1]

LO1 = layout_as_star(s1)

TwoCenters = union(s1, s2)

LO2 = LO1
LO2[1,] = c(-0.2, 0)
LO2 = rbind(LO2, c(0.2,0))

plot(TwoCenters, layout= LO2)
```

[image: Star with Two Centers]